# glDrawArrays throws GL_INVALID_OPERATION exception for specific shader

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using open gl es on android to show video with black color substituted with transparent color. But when I use my specific shader GL_INVALID_OPERATION error code.

here is my shader:

```
protected final String mFragmentShader =
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                        "vec4 color;\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "void main(){\n" +
                        "    color =  texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                        "    if(color.r < 0.1 && color.g < 0.1 && color.b < 0.1){\n" +
                        "        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);\n" +
                        "    } else{\n" +
                        "        gl_FragColor = color;\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "}";
```

When I use next shader - everything is being showed well(except transparency of course)

```
 protected final String mFragmentShader =
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                        "void main() {\n" +
                        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                        "}\n";
```

Here is my onDrawFrame code:

```
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
            if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                return;
            synchronized (this) {
                if (updateSurface) {
                    mSurface.updateTexImage();
                    mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
                    updateSurface = false;
                }
            }

            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            checkGlError("glUseProgram");

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
            GLES20.glFinish();

        }
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: Doesn't OpenGL ES have `glGetShaderInfoLog`? Have you checked if the shader info log contains anything useful?

Comment: Shouldn't it be mTriangleVerticesData and mTriangleTextureData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in float precision. When I set `precision mediump float` in first shader everything started working well

Answer (score -1):

In your first shader you are using `color.r` when you should be using `color.x` and so on. The `vec4` object is an object with members `x,y,z,w`

Comment: When changed to x y z - nothing was shown at all. See my answer for solution of my problem

Comment: No, GLSL allows various styles of member access, like `xyzw`, `rgba` and `stpq`. You just can't mix them, like `xgs` (which the OP doesn't do).